# Как убрать класс required у label?

Tags: php, symfony2

```
->add("document_type", ChoiceType::class, [
    "choices_as_values" => true,
    "choices"           => [
        "Create new document" => "1",
        "Upload file"         => "2"
    ],
    'choice_attr'       => function ($val, $key, $index) {
        if ($index == 1) {
            return ['checked' => true];
        } else {
            return [];
        }

    },
    "attr"              => ["class" => "hide_switch"],
    "label_attr"        => ["class" => "test"],
    "expanded"          => true,
    "multiple"          => false,
    "mapped"            => false
])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**required => false Не предлагать**

Answer (score 1):

Чем не нравится `required = false`?

В противном случае, нужно править уже на уровне вывода виджета. Я не знаю какой движок вы используете, но предполагаю, что twig. Тогда вывод должен происходить примерно следующим образом:

```
form_widget(form.document_type, {attr: {required: false} })
```

Вместо false можно попробовать null.